# Vb.net kill process

Tags: vb.net, rdp, kill-process, terminal-services

I've a problem to resolve that is:
I need to kill some process when a user disconnect (not logg off) his rdp session.

This is an app which makes an established connection that is running for ever if the user forget logging off his Windows Rdp session  and what i need is to kill it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an application that does the following:

- [Enumerate all RDP sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13987213/87698) and find out which are disconnected.
- [Enumerate all processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648410/87698) and find out which (a) belong to your target app and (b) belong to a disconnected session.
- [Kindly ask the app to close itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use task scheduler to run this application every few minutes with administrative permissions.