# C#: Check if current user is disconnected

Tags: c#, windows

In C#, how to check programatically if the current user is in Windows 'Disconnected' state?

Background: On a server, I would like all instances of my program to selv-terminate if the current user is disconnected.

The program is not running in elevated state, i.e. not as administrator.

Comment: "Disconnected" as in not connected to RDP, or in the lock screen?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core? Or .NET Framework? Or is this a class library and you're using .NET Standard?

Comment: Have a look at the [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=net-5.0) event if it fits your needs.

Comment: "Disconnected" as in not connected to RDP.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc) to hook into the Windows System Messages. This will not be possible if you're in a console app.

see: [Detect Active RDP sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204041/detect-active-rdp-session)

Comment: Thank you @Victor, I was able to make it work.  : )

I tried inserting a set of working code, but was not allowed.